# Java Generic array creation allowed?

Tags: java, arrays, generics

```
class jj<T> {
T ob;
jj(T ob) {
    this.ob = ob;
}

void show() {
    System.out.println(ob);
}}
class demo {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // jj<Integer>[] lol=new jj<Integer>[10];// Not Allowed
    jj<Integer>[] lol = new jj[10];//But this is allowed why?
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        lol[i] = new jj<>(i * 10);

    for (jj<Integer> x : lol)
        x.show();

}
```

Why the above code is allowed if generics arrays are not allowed in java? plz help!

Comment: Allowed, yes, but the compiler is going to give you a warning that you should respect.

Comment: Thanks but can u elaborate? i mean jj<Integer>[] lol=new jj<Integer>[10]; is not allowed in java but jj<Integer>[] lol = new jj[10]; is allowed why?(what is happening in background) and compiler gives no warning.

Comment: Oracle JDK 8u131 gives me a warning on compile of the code: `Note: GenericArrays.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.` `Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.`. Compiling with `-Xlint:unchecked` gives `GenericArrays.java:6: warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion` `jj<Integer>[] lol = new jj[10];// But this is allowed why?` with `new` underlined. As does my Eclipse Neon.1 install using the same JDK: `Type safety: The expression of type jj[] needs unchecked conversion to conform to jj<Integer>[]`. Perhaps some warnings are turned off in your compiler (+ possible IDE) setup?

Comment: Just as a note, please stick to naming conventions. Class names should start with an upper-case letter (camelcase). Methods and variables with a lower-case letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is allowed because `new jj[10]` is not a generic array (e.g. `new T[10]`), but is instead an array of raw `jj` instances - `jj` with its generic arguments omitted. `new jj[10]` creates a new array of raw `jj`, not a new array of `jj<Integer>`.  Java allows one to force instances of a raw type to be assigned to a reference of type with generic arguments as the code does with `jj<Integer>[] lol = new jj[10];`.  I believe this is there for backwards compatibility with pre-Java 5 code.

Comment: "*backwards compatibility with pre-Java 5 code*" - yeah, it is called **raw-type** and should **not be used** since it has no advantages compared to `jj<Object>` which should be used instead (if one truly wants to allow all objects).

Comment: Raw types! Yes, that's the term I was looking for. Answer updated accordingly. Thanks, @Zabuza.

Comment: You've welcome, @JagjotSingh. :) Glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

Generic arrays are allowed. The compiler is going to give you a warning because the generics implement type erasure meaning that they do not exist at run time. The compiler will give you a warning when creating a generic reference, and for the object's type you need to have a object array that is casted.

CAN'T do this:

```
//SYNTAX ERROR
jj = new T[10];
```

But CAN do this:

```
//This suppresses the unchecked-cast warning that the compiler will give
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") 
//Can't create a generic array but can create an Object array and cast it to be a //compatible type
T[] jj = (T[])new Object[10];
```

However in the code above is not creating a generic array, instead it is creating an array of the class `jj` that has a generic in it.

Comment: Also it is better convention to use the generic name `E[]` instead of `T[]` for a collection of items.